# C# and PDFsharp to merge 2 pdf files in a directory by their name. There are many

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Hey guys bear with me since i'm fairly new to C# and visual studio.

I have a bunch of PDF's that get dumped into a directory.  Usually around 300.  Each PDF looks like this

TP031041
TP031041_1
TP031337
TP031337_1
...ETC

The way its done manually is to combine the file number with its identical file number + the underscore and 1
so

TP031041 + TP031041_1 and after they merge, to keep the name of the first file so
TP031041 + TP031041_1 = TP031041

EDIT: This is the working code after many trial and error:

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string dir = @"C:\Users\Pr0x1mo\Desktop\IMAGES\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //files in files folder and named like: TP031041 TP031041 TP031337 TP031337_1
            File.SetAttributes(dir, FileAttributes.Normal);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf");
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> groups = files.GroupBy(n => n.Split('.')[0].Split('_')[0]);
            //string f = files[0].Split('_')[0];
            foreach (var items in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items.Key);
                PdfDocument outputPDFDocument = new PdfDocument();
                foreach (var pdfFile in items)
                {
                    Merge(outputPDFDocument, pdfFile);
                }
                outputPDFDocument.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(items.Key) + @"\Merge\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(items.Key) + ".pdf");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void Merge(PdfDocument outputPDFDocument, string pdfFile)
        {
            PdfDocument inputPDFDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            outputPDFDocument.Version = inputPDFDocument.Version;
            foreach (PdfPage page in inputPDFDocument.Pages)
            {
                outputPDFDocument.AddPage(page);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: new code that works

So this is the new code i edited to thanks to murat and my friend for suggestions.

Comment: the list of files to combine is taken from the `OpenFileDialog`. it will return a list of paths when you confirm it with a multiple selection. "none of this works"... compiler errors, runtime exception, which? how could there ever be duplicates when all source files are located in the same directory?

Comment: meta, why is the code red? it looks like an unterminated string constant would, but there is none. has SO code view started to misparse the @ syntax?

Comment: @dlatikay The first error is The Name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context. the next is The Name 'openFileDialog1' does not exist in the current context.  and Program does not contain a static "Main" method suitable for any entry point.

Comment: Your question is not about *itext*  so I will delete the tag.

Comment: so this means you need a version of that code without a GUI, that reads the list of files to merge from a directory and not from a windows "open..." dialog. Probably its best to start with `Directory.GetFiles()` [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @dlatikay it is because of the backslash directly before the quote that ends the string. Apparently the highlighter incorrectly assumes that quote to be escaped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the approach below;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

namespace pdf_merger
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //files in files folder and named like: TP031041 TP031041 TP031337 TP031337_1
            var files = Directory.GetFiles("files", "*.pdf");
            var groups = files.GroupBy(n => n.Split('.')[0].Split('_')[0]);

            foreach (var items in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items.Key);
                PdfDocument outputPDFDocument = new PdfDocument();
                foreach (var pdfFile in items)
                {
                    Merge(outputPDFDocument, pdfFile);
                }

                outputPDFDocument.Save(items.Key.Replace("files", "files/compiled") + ".pdf");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Merge(PdfDocument outputPDFDocument, string pdfFile)
        {
            PdfDocument inputPDFDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            outputPDFDocument.Version = inputPDFDocument.Version;
            foreach (PdfPage page in inputPDFDocument.Pages)
            {
                outputPDFDocument.AddPage(page);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how does this know which directory my pdf files are in ?  I tried running the code and and it gave me this error:  System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

  Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\XBorja\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\files'.

Comment: I know the directory which you dumped your pdf right? So you change this line var files = Directory.GetFiles("files", "*.pdf"); first parameter is the directory physical address.

The code getting list of pdf files in the directory which is called "files" in debug folder

Comment: ok so i edited my code to match your with the way the directory is supposed to be... i execute the code but all that happens is that a blank cmd prompt comes up and just remains blank without doing anything.  When i hit enter it just closes and nothing is done.

Comment: there are pdfs in files folder, aren't they?

Comment: Yes.  The way my code is now in the edit is correct right?

Answer (score 1):

The method `MergeMultiplePDFIntoSinglePDF` will combine all files to one PDF, but doesn't include the grouping logic you'd like. 
One way would be to sort the filenames in a list and then group them by prefix.

```
//example data. replace with files = openFileDialog.FileNames
var files = new List<string> 
{ 
    "TP031337_1", 
    "TP031041", 
    "TP031041", 
    "TP031041_1", 
    "TP031337", 
    "TP031337_1"        
};

var groupedFiles = files.Distinct()
                      .OrderBy(s => s)
                      .GroupBy(s => s.Split('_')[0]);
foreach (var group in groupedFiles)
{
    MergeMultiplePDFIntoSinglePDF(group.First(), group.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the way they get dumped into my directory they're already sorted out in order the way you posted above.

Comment: Just in case I've added OrderBy to sort the entries by name.

Comment: In this code, i see you put in the numbers i listed.. the numbers i listed where just example numbers, so do i have to write in there the actual numbers of my pdf files every time i use this?

Comment: No, you can replace `files` with `openFileDialog1.FileNames`